# How to securly transfer UUID from server to an android app before authentication

Tags: security, cryptography

Im currently having this scenario where i need to make sure that a UUID ( which is sensitive in nature) needs to be send from server to an android app before authentication has happened. However i want to make sure that this UUID is obtained only to my valid customers and not to general public. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply have the client connect over TLS and then transfer the secret data that way? It works and is well understood!

Comment: Yes this would allow to securly transfer to client. But how will i make sure UUID is only obtained to my valid customer. I dont want everyone to access the UUID and this should be done before authentication.

Comment: if you want to share something with someone, then you need to understand who the person is, which means there needs to be an authentication step before all of this happens. can you use device authentication before user authn?